# Angular /CSS Remove top Border of Dynamic data rendered by ngFor - Remove top border ONLY for First row

Tags: html, css, angular

I Have a html like this

```
 <div class="scx-individual-supplier" *ngFor="let request of suppliers" >
      <div>
      <scx-indv-supplier
          class="row"
          *ngIf="!(request.status === 'CANCELLED' && request.durationDays > 179)"
          [request]="request"
          [requestId]="request.requestId"
        ></scx-indv-supplier>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Applied CSS to scx-individual-supplier and used first child but it does not remove top border for the first row

```
.scx-individual-supplier{
  border-top: 1px solid #d0c9c9;
}

.scx-individual-supplier:first-child {
  border-top: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a border to the parent element, or to the child `div` element?

Comment: PARENT element  <div class="scx-individual-supplier" *ngFor="let request of suppliers" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index of ngFor:
`*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"`
Then in your element use
`[ngClass]={i === 0 ? 'styleWithoutTopBorder' : 'styleWithTopBorder'}`

The ? is a ternary expression that will pick the css-class depending on the result of i === 0.

update: with code

css:

> ```
> .noTopBorder {
>   border: '1px solid black';
>   border-top: none;
> }
>
> .withTopBorder {
>     border: '1px solid black';
> }
> ```

html:

> ```
>  <div class="scx-individual-supplier" *ngFor="let request of suppliers; let i = index" [ngClass]="{i === 0 ? 'noTopBorder' : 'withTopBorder'}" >
>       <div>
>       <scx-indv-supplier
>           class="row"
>           *ngIf="!(request.status === 'CANCELLED' && request.durationDays > 179)"
>           [request]="request"
>           [requestId]="request.requestId"
>         ></scx-indv-supplier>
>       </div>
>     </div>
> <div>
> ```

Comment: @nickolas This is the only right way when styling items in a loop depending on its index.

Comment: can you write css for this

Comment: your code throws error Missing expected : at column 4 in [{i === 0 ? 'noTopBorder' : 'withTopBorder'}] in ng:///SuppliersModule/SuppliersComponent.html@45:88 ("

Comment: Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 4 in [{i === 0 ? 'noTopBorder' : 'withTopBorder'}] in ng:///SuppliersModule/SuppliersComponent.html@59:2 ("
  <div class="scx-individual-supplier" 
  *ngFor="let request of suppliers; let i = index" 
  [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{i === 0 ? 'noTopBorder' : 'withTopBorder'}" >

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first` variable provided by `ngFor`:

```
<div class="scx-individual-supplier" *ngFor="let request of suppliers; first as isFirst" [class.no-border]="isFirst" >
   <div>
      <scx-indv-supplier
          class="row"
          *ngIf="!(request.status === 'CANCELLED' && request.durationDays > 179)"
          [request]="request"
          [requestId]="request.requestId"
        ></scx-indv-supplier>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about css any change to write in css

Comment: can you write css for that

Comment: .no-border {
  border-top: none;
}  is this correct css

Comment: but this does not remove my border on top for first row What is first?

Comment: @nickolas https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables